# How do I edit a single object from an array of objects without the other objects following the object that I am trying to edit?

Tags: modifiers, texture-painting

I am trying to create a domino animation through blender and I used the array command to create multiple dominos. Now I am trying to edit the first domino to put a photo on it however the photo is also applied to the following dominos. How will I be able to edit each domino individually?

Comment: You can't, or you need to apply the Array modifier

Comment: Best thing you can do is set your 1st domino correctly with good uv, texture, materials and all, then apply array modifier and change those you want by giving them different textures